# Python3: Printing a space after a text using input() and textwrap()

Tags: python-3.x, input, word-wrap

Im typing a line of code that is printing a string then right after, it prints the user input.

Name = input(textwrap.fill("Gerald: Hello adventurer, what is thy name?: ", width = 42))
                   ^
It is not print this space.
I want it to print the space have the result to be.
...what is thy name?: Name of adventurer 
                                    ^
with a space after the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
import textwrap

Name = input(textwrap.fill("Gerald: Hello adventurer, what is thy name?: ", width=42, drop_whitespace=False))
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.drop_whitespace